# How can I define one Java annotation in terms of another?

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation

For example, I'd like to have `@Nonnegative`, defined as `@Min(0)`, and `@DaySeconds`, defined as `@Min(0) @Max(86399)`.

Comment: do you mean nested annotations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [`@Min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html) and [`@Max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html) annotations can be used on annotations themselves. This is called [constraint composition](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/ch06.html#section-constraint-composition).

As such, you can define a new constraint `DaySeconds` like this:

```
@Min(0)
@Max(86399)
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
public @interface DaySeconds {

    String message() default "{your.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

It would be the same for `@Nonnegative`.